# Order of execution and which one is faster

Tags: sql, sql-server

This is a sample code, is the order of execution of 'where' clause different in both these queries? Should I expect the second query to run faster than first?

```
SELECT A.* 
FROM TABLE1 A 
INNER JOIN TABLE2 B 
ON A.COLUMN3=B.COLUMN3 
WHERE A.COLUMN1 = 2 AND B.COLUMN2 = 4
```

VS

```
SELECT A.* 
FROM  (SELECT * FROM TABLE1 WHERE TABLE1.COLUMN1 =2)A 
INNER JOIN (SELECT * FROM TABLE2 WHERE TABLE2.COLUMN2 = 4)B 
ON A.COLUMN3=B.COLUMN3
```

Comment: I get identical plans.

Comment: I would be very surprised if those would show any difference with any modern optimizer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will get exactly the same execution plans.

In the second example you have manually pushed the predicates down against `TABLE1` and `TABLE2` before the join.

For the simple case of an `inner join ... where` against base tables this is something the optimiser will definitely consider on its own without any additional help. It has rules to try and push filters down as far as possible to reduce row counts early.

This is still a technique that occasionally is useful to work around specific optimiser limitations (as in the examples below with an outer join and a [window partition](https://sqlperformance.com/2013/03/t-sql-queries/the-problem-with-window-functions-and-views)) but I would not expect it to be useful in the case in the question.

### Examples where manual predicate pushing is useful

```
CREATE TABLE #T1(X INT, Y INT, PRIMARY KEY(X,Y));

INSERT INTO #T1 
SELECT TOP 100000 ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY @@SPID), 1
FROM sys.all_objects o1, sys.all_objects o2

SELECT *
FROM #T1 T1
LEFT JOIN #T1 T2 ON T1.X = T2.X AND T2.X = 12345;

SELECT *
FROM #T1 T1
LEFT JOIN (SELECT * FROM #T1 WHERE X = 12345) T2 ON T1.X = T2.X;

DECLARE @X INT = 12345;

WITH T AS (SELECT *, 
                  ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY X ORDER BY Y) AS  RN 
           FROM #T1)
SELECT *
FROM T 
WHERE X = @X;

WITH T AS (SELECT *, 
                  ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY X ORDER BY Y) AS  RN 
           FROM #T1
           WHERE X = @X)
SELECT *
FROM T;
```

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 2):

I would expect the first to be at least as fast as the second if not faster because the shape of the query is a very common one that has been well analyzed and optimized.

That being said SQL Server is rather mature and it could logically 'rewrite' the second query to execute exactly the same plan and performance as the first.

*[Note that SQL is not a procedural language, we're not really saying what order to do things in, but rather describing which rows/columns we want with which conditions. If two differently written queries mean exactly the same thing the database can do anything internally as long as the expected rows are returned. It is sometimes the case though that how we write it can and does affect performance.]*

Use `EXPLAIN` on each query to see the differences in query plans and expected costs.